# How to append a string at the beginning to every tuple within a list?

Tags: string, python-3.x, tuples

```
 tuple_list = [('1','2'),('2','3'),('2','6')]
 string = Point

 Desired_List = [Point('1','2'),Point('2','3'),Point('2','6')]
```

I have tried the following code:

```
   for x in tuple_list:
    x.append("Point")

   for x in tuple_list:
    x + 'Point'
```

How to append a string at the beginning to every tuple within a list?

Updates for your info, I have 2 columns and hundreds of rows in csv file of x and y points:

```
x    y
1    3
2    4
```

I want to get that as:

```
Points = [Point(1,3),Point(2,4),......]
```

Comment: You can't append a string to the beginning of a Tuple - those are [NamedTuples](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.namedtuple)

Comment: Could just define a quick `class Point: def __init__(self): self.x = None, self.y = None` and have your list of objects.

Comment: What's that `Desired_List` supposed to be? What is that `Point` supposed to be? In your example, it looks like a class that you instantiate for each tuple, which has nothing to do with that tuple or string manipulation you were asking for. Please improve that example code so one can understand what's going on. See [PEP 8 Naming Conventions](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#naming-conventions) for more information on how.

Comment: @Jeronimo Please see the updates above

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If strings are all you need, this is the way to go :

```
desired_list = []
for x,y in tuple_list:
    desired_list.append(f"Point({x},{y})")
```

Which produces the following output :

```
>>> print(desired_list)
['Point(1,2)', 'Point(2,3)', 'Point(2,6)']
```

As far as named tuples are concerned, you'd do it as follows :

```
from collections import namedtuple
Point = namedtuple('Point', ['x', 'y'])
tuple_list = [('1','2'),('2','3'),('2','6')]
desired_list = []
for x,y in tuple_list:
    desired_list.append(Point(x, y))
```

And the corresponding result is :

```
>>> print(desired_list)
[Point(x='1', y='2'), Point(x='2', y='3'), Point(x='2', y='6')]
```